# modify url via htaccess passing and capturing two parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I need to pass two parameters via url when accessing the archive.php page.
The URL is the same as sitename.com/archive.php?page="2"&category="car".
I would like htaccess to become like this
sitename.com/car/2/
Next I would like to capture the two parameters.
Can anyone explain to me how to edit the htaccess file and how to capture the two parameters from the URL.
My current htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml ./sitemap.php [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ core.php [L]
```

page core.php:

```
<?php include './include/include.php'; ?>
<?php require './config.php'; ?>
<?php 
$url = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
$cleanUrl = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$st2 = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_article WHERE url = '$cleanUrl'");
while($recordArt = $st2->fetch()){
    $artUrl = $recordArt['url'];
    }
if($artUrl !== $cleanUrl){
$st = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM sb_category WHERE categoria = '$cleanUrl'");
while($recordCat = $st->fetch()){
    $catTit = $recordCat['categoria'];
    }
}

switch($cleanUrl){
    case $artUrl:
        single();
    break;
    case $catTit:
        echo "sono una categoria";
    break;
    case "contatti":
        echo "sono una la pagina contatti";
    break;
    default:
    echo "articolo non trovato";
    break;
}


function single(){
    $urlArticle = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    require './include/include.php';
    require './classes/class.single.php';

    $single= new showArticle($urlArticle, $PDO);
    $showSingle = $single->single();

    if($showSingle !== NULL){ foreach($showSingle as $list){
        $id = $list['id'];
        $titolo = $list['titolo'];
        $testo = html_entity_decode($list['testo']);
        $descrizione = $list['descrizione'];
        $categoria = $list['categoria'];
        $url = $list['url'];
        $img = $list['img'];
        $data = $list['data'];}}

    require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/single.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to solve the problem. The url is not changed. I try to explain myself better.
I have this address

localhost/simpleblog/archive.php?Page=2&category=car

i want to convert it to

localhost/simpleblog/archive/2/car

my current htaccess is this:

```
RewriteEngine ON
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

DirectoryIndex home.php

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml ./sitemap.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ core.php [L]
```